# Why do we still need QEMU while KVM is also a hypervisor?

Tags: linux-kernel, virtualization, kvm

I have known that `KVM` is a module of `Linux Kernel`, `KVM` converts Linux into a type-1 (bare-metal) hypervisor. Show why we need `QEMU` to work with `KVM`? Is these any feature that `QEMU` has but `KVM` doesn't?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388305/is-this-an-appropriate-edit-placing-all-technical-term-in-code-tags/388308#388308

Comment: Please see this thread --> https://serverfault.com/questions/208693/difference-between-kvm-and-qemu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the difference between KVM and QEMU?

QEMU uses emulation; KVM uses processor extensions (HVM) for virtualization.

http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/FAQ#General_KVM_information

Comment: So, can Linux Kernel with stand-alone KVM module operate as a Hypervisor?

Comment: "Unlike native QEMU, which uses emulation, KVM is a special operating mode of QEMU that uses CPU extensions (HVM) for virtualization via a kernel module. ", So No you would need to have Qemu installed to run VM's. --> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KVM